# d3 SVG drag drop plus rotate with button

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, drag-and-drop

I'm attempting to create a program where an image can be dragged and dropped but also rotated at the push of a button(after being dragged, and rotated on its own axis). I can successfully make an image drag and drop but cannot get the rotate to work correctly. I think the solution would be to use a "transform","translate" for positioning the image at the start; and for the dragging instead of "d3.event" however I am unsure of how to do this. I'm using SVG with d3 library. I wish to keep my: dragstarted, dragged and dragended separate as will be adding further code later.

```js
    var svgWidth = parseInt(document.getElementById("canvas").getAttribute("width")),
    selected = null;
    canvas = d3.select('#canvas');

    canvas.append("image")
            .attr('width', 17)
            .attr('height', 59)
            .attr("x", svgWidth - 40)
            .attr("y", 100)
            .attr("xlink:href", "https://lorempixel.com/100/100/cats")
            .call(d3.drag()
                    .on("start", dragstarted)
                    .on("drag", dragged)
                    .on("end", dragended));


    canvas.append("image")
            .attr('width', 80)
            .attr('height', 38)
            .attr("x", svgWidth - 90)
            .attr("y", 200)
            .attr("xlink:href", "https://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports")
            .call(d3.drag()
                    .on("start", dragstarted)
                    .on("drag", dragged)
                    .on("end", dragended));

    function dragstarted(d){
        d3.select(this).raise().classed("active", true);
    }

    function dragged(d){
        d3.select(this)
                .attr("x", d3.event.x - parseInt(d3.select('image').attr("width")) / 2)
                .attr("y", d3.event.y - parseInt(d3.select('image').attr("height")) / 2);
    }

    function dragended(d){
        d3.select(this).classed("active", false);
        selected = this;
    }

    window.onload=function(){
        document.getElementById("rotate").addEventListener("click", function(){
            if(selected != null){
                var x = selected.getAttribute("x"),
                        y = selected.getAttribute("y");
                selected.setAttribute("transform","translate(" + x / 2 + "," + y / 2 +")" + "rotate(90)");
            }
        });
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.8.0/d3.min.js">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <svg id="canvas" width="960px" height="500px"></svg>
    <button id="rotate">Rotate</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I fixed it. Didn't realise the x and y values didn't have to be set on the images to use d3.event.x and d3.event.y . Meaning I could use those values on the transform when the image was being dragged.